# What is the Objective-C equivalent of Java's parseInt()?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

m anew comer to iPhone...before i have developed for Android..Could any one tell me what is the alternate code in objective C..Thanx in advance

```
Int projectNumber = Integer.parseInt(projectNumber.trim());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int intProjectNumber = [[projectNumber stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet] integerValue];
```

edit:
Just to explain a bit more..

If you have a NSString named projectNumber (ie. @"    4 "). You can make a new string with trimed whitespace infront of the string and after the string with

```
NSString *trimedProjectNumber = [projectNumber stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet];
```

as you can see this replaces the trim() function

trimedProjectNumber would now be @"4". If you want an integer representation of this string you do:

```
int intProjectNumber = [trimedProjectNumber integerValue];
```

this replaces the parseInt..

I dont know java but i think this is what youre code does? If not explain what the java code does..

Comment: You actually don't need to trim the white space, since integerValue skips it anyway.  And to return an int, you should use -intValue

Comment: what if I have @"A" in variable projectNumber ? in Java I have an Exception which I can catch and do appropriate action (return passed the defaultValue for example).